# Need help changing the color of the ActionBar Title Text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've tried many different approaches to changing the Title Text in the ActionBar including the Google supplied one, and yet no success.

My Styles:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle"> @style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle"> @style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle"> @style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle"> @style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@color/textcolor</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@color/textcolor</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Please help, I have been stuck on this for a whole day now, I'm considering skipping this step but it would look so much better if I changed it. If you need more information let me know.

Comment: why not use Toolbar?

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet that requires API level 21, I am using a minimum of 16.

Comment: @ChonBonStudios You are using AppCompat which means the `Toolbar` is a min api of 7. Please read up on the libraries you are using: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a support theme (AppCompat) you need to specify backward-compatible attributes too:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle"> @style/MyActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle"> @style/MyActionBar</item>
```

Try that with all of the attributes.

**Edit:**

Please follow the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html). I see some attributes out of place. Also make don't use `Holo` widgets with the `AppCompat` theme.

Try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme"
       parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"  parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You no longer need the `android:` attributes for AppCompat v21+

Comment: I did this and now my text is gone lol, i checked to make sure that the background color and text were not the same and they aren't, so I have no idea what is going on now.

Comment: @ChonBonStudios did you add the `android:`-less attributes to other styles too?

Comment: Yes I did, at first I didn't, only for the MyActionBar reference, but still no luck. I updated my styles.

Comment: @ChonBonStudios I've updated my answer. Give it a shot.